# Ajax client for a CXF service

Tags: ajax, webclient, cxf

I'm new to CXF, and I was trying to implement a CFX client in Ajax. 
I had already implemented a client in Java but now I need to implement a client-side application to access CXF. I'm not even sure that it's possible to do that (Accessing CXF directly from client-side).
If it's possible then kindly direct me to some ajax code. If not, then please help me with your ideas for a web-based CFX client.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would like to know a good answer to this question too. However, I have what I deem to be an unsatisfactory answer!  Code up a servlet that effectively wraps the java-based JAX-RS client so as to make it accessible via a 'normal' parameter-based web services API call (i.e. like http://mydomain:8080/service?param1=xxx).  This you can then use with AJAX.  However I don't like this since, in effect, the JAX-RS service is most probably already being delivered from a generic servlet (e.g. as is the case I believe for Jersey)

If anyone out there has got a better solution, I'd like to hear it.